# I am trying to unit test a Silex application but Silex\WebTestCase namespace cannot be found

Tags: symfony, phpunit, silex

I have phpunit 3.6.12 installed as well as Silex. In the root directory of my app I have  tests directory which contains the trivial test file BlogFunctionTest.php

```
<?

use Silex\WebTestCase;

// BLOG: Front end test
class BlogFunctionalTest extends Silex\WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->assertGreaterThan(0, 1);
    }
}

?>
```

when I run phpunit from the command line I get the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Silex\WebTestCase' not found in {path}/BlogFunctionTest.php line 7
```

which refers to the line where I try to extend WebTestCase. The same happens if I replace

```
use Silex\WebTestCase;
```

with

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
```

Silex is installed in relative to my test file at

```
../vendor/silex/
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to define a bootstrap inside phpunit.xml.dist which point to the bootstrap of your silex application like it's done here https://github.com/joshuamorse/Silex-Boilerplate/blob/master/phpunit.xml.dist

Comment: That was the ticket. Thank you!